# Amazon AWS Web application deployment using custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have bought my domain www.xxxxxxxxxx.com from godaddy.

My web app is built using Java & Angular JS....

I want to deploy my web app in Amazon AWS with the domain that I have bought from GoDaddy .....

Some references in Google tell me to use Elastic beanstalk.
But I am not sure to go...

First I want to use my domain .. How to use the domain in Amazon and how to configure that.

Tried changing nameservers and A records. No luck....

Then I have to deploy same wars in 15 subdomains in AWS... Is there a better way to achieve this.

I couldn't find a single brief explanation regarding domain name configuration and web app deployment ..

Please suggest me ....

Comment: EC2 , EBS, both give you a URL to your application once deployed. You can then manage your DNS from godaddy dashboard and point the CNAME to these URLs.

Comment: So ur point is that u have to create an application in EBS and deploy the war there and I will get an url once done. I have add CNAME record as this url on GoDaddy.. Am I right @Shikar Chauhan

Comment: Yes. CNAME records are aliases, so your application will be served at the domain you purchased. You can have as many subdomains you want, though they will be pointed to separate deployments. Also, if you have Angular app communicating with the backend over REST, you can deploy frontend on CloudFront or Surge.sh.

Comment: Shikar Thanks for ur quick response.. I try that now.. also please let me know if I have any idea... If I deploy as many wars in seperate subdomains.. How could the AWS calculate the cost